# SQLAlchemy: How to delete a item on one-to-many relation?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy, and i want to delete certain item in a one-to-many-relationship. Well there are two pictures for you. First you can see an EER-Model. Its a one (*gender*) to many (*person*) relation.

[image]

Second, you can see a table with fictional data. In *gender*-table we have two gender currently, and in *person*-table we have three persons.
[image]

Imagine, you will just delete a gender, let us say 'male'. But we see, that 'male' is used as foreign by *person*-table.

My current source code looks as follows:

```
class PERSON_GENDER(Base):

    __tablename__ = "person_gender"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    gender = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

class PERSON(Base):

    __tablename__ = "person"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    nickname = Column(String(255))
    alias_name  = Column(String (255))
    name_normally_used = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    first_middle_name = Column(String(255))
    last_name = Column(String(100))
    birth_name = Column(String(100))
    body_height = Column(String(10))
    wedding_anniversary = Column(Date)
    birthday = Column(Date)
    day_of_death = Column(Date)
    notice = Column(Text())

    gender_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person_gender.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    gender = relationship("PERSON_GENDER", single_parent=True, cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
```

When I run this one, then not only the gender is deleted, but also the person. I want that only the gender is deleted, not the person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ondelete='CASCADE')=> ondelete='SET NULL')